# How to create a type that is string?

Tags: delphi, types, delphi-5

A [blog entry from Raymond Chen today](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/01/24/10387757.aspx) made me realize the elegant solution to a problem i'm having.

Various **shell** functions, rather than all taking `ITEM­ID­LIST` structure, can be made to only accept:

- `ITEM­ID_CHILD`
- `ID­LIST_RELATIVE`
- `ID­LIST_ABSOLUTE`
- `ITEM­ID_CHILD_ARRAY`

structures. The structures are all **identical**, but now you can enforce *conceptual* types at the compiler level.

### Back to Delphi

i have a set of functions:

- some **only** take a path: (e.g. `C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\AllisonAngel.jpg`)
- some **only** take a filename: (e.g. `AllisonAngel.jpg`)
- some **only** take a folder: (e.g. `C:\Users\Ian\Desktop`)

And right now they're all declared as `string`, e.g.:

```
 function GetFilenames(Folder: string; ...): ...
 function IsValidBatchFilename(Path: string): ...
 function GetReportType(Filename: string): ...
```

and i have to trust that i'm passing the right stuff; and i'm trusting that developers (e.g. *me*), know the difference between:

- a **path**
- a **filename**
- and a **folder**

i want to change the functions to use *"typed"* strings:

```
 function GetFilenames(Folder: TFolderOnly; ...): ...
 function IsValidBatchFilename(Path: TFullPath): ...
 function GetReportType(Filename: TFilenameOnly): ...
```

Where:

```
type
   TFullPath = type string;
   TFolderOnly = type string;
   TFilenameOnly = type string;
```

Except that there's no actual typing happening:

```
var
   dropFolder: string;
begin
   dropFolder := GetDropFolderPath(LCT);

   GetFilenames(dropFolder); <-- no compile error

end;
```

What i want is a *"distinct"* type of string; that is `string` insofar that it is length prefixed, reference counted, null terminated.

Comment: That's where Delphi is comparing e.g. to C# is weak. This is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use advanced records to accomplish this. For instance, you could do

```
type
  TFileName = record
    FFileName: string;
  public
    class function IsValidFileName(const S: string): boolean; static;
    class operator Implicit(const S: string): TFileName;
    class operator Implicit(const S: TFileName): string;
  end;

implementation

class function TFileName.IsValidFileName(const S: string): boolean;
begin
  result := true {TODO};
end;

class operator TFileName.Implicit(const S: string): TFileName;
begin
  if IsValidFileName(S) then
    result.FFileName := S
  else
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid file name: "%s"', [S]);
end;

class operator TFileName.Implicit(const S: TFileName): string;
begin
  result := S.FFileName;
end;
```

and similarly for `TPath` and `TFolder`. Advantages:

- A function expecting `TPath` will not accept a `TFileName` (or some other combination).
- You can still assign a `TPath` to/from a regular string. If you cast from a string to a `TPath`, you will automatically check the string to see if it contains a valid path.
- Optionally, you can specify how a `TPath` can be assigned to a `TFileName` (or some other combination), by writing more `Implicit` class operators.

Comment: Although I don't think it's possible in Delphi 5, it's a good idea! [+1]

Comment: @TLama i wasn't going to say anything; and just accept the most popular answer.

Answer (score 8):

Create different record types for each string type. Distinct record types are not assignment-compatible, even though string types are.

```
type
  TFullPath = record value: string end;
  TFolderOnly = record value: string end;
```

Chen's article compares the new shell feature to the classic STRICT macro that makes distinct handle types, and as I recall, declaring distinct structs is exactly how the STRICT macro works.

Comment: Will reference counting be maintained if I copy instances of `TFullPaths`?  (e.g. `FullPath2 := FullPath1;`)

Comment: Yes, strings inside records are assigned the same as strings anywhere else, @Afrazier.

Answer (score 2):

With the way Delphi handles basic types, I'm pretty this is a case of "you can't get there from here."

Your string type declarations are all going to satisfy Delphi's rules for type compatibility and assignment compatibility.  What they will restrict is procedural declarations with `var` parameters.  If you changed your function declarations to be var parameters instead of reference or value parameters, you would get a compile error in your final example.

All that said, it's all useless anyway.  You still have no way to ensure that the input is only a filename, even with the `TFilenameOnly` type, and must test the contents in your procedures anyway.

Comment: If the [caller wants to use a big enough hammer to smash a square peg in a round hole](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/03/28/10288227.aspx), that's not a problem. But it does solve the problem of putting a *red* round peg in a hole meant for *green* round pegs.

Comment: It doesn't solve any problems for your color blind users.  :-P  The problem with aliases for simple types is that you don't have any way to ensure that the contents are correct.  It's attacking the problem at the wrong level of abstraction.  If you switched to classes or advanced records where the value can be validated in code at assignment, then you'd have something.  At best, type alises in Delphi are nothing more than semantic hints to other programmers.

Comment: That's why i didn't want an *alias*, but a distinct *type* (which was why i didn't declare it as `TFolder = string`, but `TFolder = type string`)

Comment: The thing is that the types are still highly compatible.  [Delphi's Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Declaring_Types) calls this out explicitly: `[...]if your purpose in defining a new type is to utilize runtime type information, for example, to associate a property editor with properties of a particular type - the distinction between 'different name' and 'different type' becomes important.)`  Behind the declaration, they're still just strings.

Comment: Except when you declare `TGirth = type TSize;`. Even though the types are still highly compatible, and behind the declaration they're identical memory layouts corresponding to `TSize`, the compiler can give semantic meaning to `TGirth` over `TSize` - and make them distinct. It *works* in Delphi if you `type` a record, but doesn't work if you `type` a string.

Comment: While I can't answer *why* this is the case, this incongruity is documented: [Type Compatibility and Identity](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity)  Most of the conditions revolve around simple types, strings, and variants.